# How to add (clone) div with fadein animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

A div box with class `.my-row` contain add and remove button with ID `#add-row` and `#remove-row` respectively. Jquery is used to clone div box on click over `#add-row` button and to remove div box using `#remove-row` button. I want fadein and fade-out animation while adding and removing div box.

HTML:

```
<div id="my-field">
   <div class="grey-field">

//box i want to clone 
  <div class="my-row">
  <a id ="add-row" class="button"></a>
  <a id ="remove-row" class="button"></a>
  </div>


   </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#add-row').on('click', function() {
        var row = $('.my-row').clone(true);
        row.removeClass('my-row');
        row.insertBefore('#my-field .grey-field>div:last');
        return false;
   });

 $('#remove-row').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest("div").fadeOut(600, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: honestly what you described is not the same thing I see in the code, how can you add elements with the same id that exists ? and what are you cloning exactly ? this is a list of row objects not one that you are selecting by class.. please associate your code with the html

Comment: Now just see my edit ! Actually I got clone and remove thing, even fadeout animation while removing , I want help to get fadein animation while cloning the box

Comment: this is still wrong, but the browser is handling the mistake I guess, I'll give you the answer in a few mins

Comment: Thanks in advance for pointing my mistakes! waiting for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js:

```
$('.add-row').on('click', function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().clone(true);
    row.removeClass('my-row').css('display','none'); // I suggest you don't remove the class here because you might need it later
    row.insertBefore('#my-field .grey-field>div:last').fadeIn('slow'); // here you are inserting before the last element, maybe that's how you want it
        return false;
   });

 $('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(600, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

html:

```
<div id="my-field">
   <div class="grey-field">
      <!--box I want to clone -->
      <div class="my-row">
          <a class ="button add-row">11</a>
          <a class ="button remove-row">22</a>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/HC6fc/1/)

Comment: Thanks CME64!--> This is working for me! Even an answer given by @gomino is also working. there is only two line difference in code.

Comment: and comments :P, I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I posted my answer in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5S9bu/3/)

```
$('.add-row').on('click', function() {
    var row = $('.my-row').clone(true);
    row.removeClass('my-row');
    row.insertBefore('#my-field .grey-field>div:last').hide().fadeIn(600);
    return false;
});

$('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("div").fadeOut(600, function(){
    $(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

I took the liberty to change your id reference to class identifier instead for the reason stated below from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

> Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

Comment: Thanks gomino +1 for you !Its nice to get hide method with fadein!and its really helpful note: provided here while cloning any div.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you want to fade-in anything with the ID, not class, add-row when you click on it and fade-out ID remove-row. ID's are denoted with a "#" while classes are denoted with a "." Check your HTML to be sure if it is a class or ID, because that may be why it's not working